# sketching equations in three dimensions?

Tags: calculus

Describe and sketch the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfy the given equation or inequality.

1. $y \geq -1$
2. $z=x$

any tips on how I can sketch these equations and sketching stuff like this in general? I managed to sketch $y=1$, but I'm not sure how it will be when I have the inequality..

Comment: What did you get for $y=1$ ?

Comment: Can you describe $y=x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: for  y=1 I got a vertical plane parallel to the x-axis at y=1? and y=x in r2 is just a line, not sure how that can apply to z=x in 3d..